# Linux shell replace content in file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

guys.
There is a file named 'server.conf' and I want to use shell to change content from it.
In line 115, there is `server-bridge 192.168.50.225(ip) 255.255.0.0(mask)  192.168.10.50(begin ip) 192.168.10.90(end ip)`
 in it. I want to change the `ip`, `mask`, `begin ip` and `end ip`. For example, I plan to change

```
`server-bridge 192.168.50.225 255.255.0.0  192.168.10.50 192.168.10.90`
```

into

```
`server-bridge 192.168.10.100 255.255.0.0  192.168.10.60 192.168.10.80`
```

What should I do with `sed` or others tools? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed -i 's/server-bridge\ 192.168.50.225\ 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.50\ 192.168.10.90/server-bridge\ 192.168.10.100\ 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.60\ 192.168.10.80/' server.conf

You can also create a simple script where  new values to be replaced are stored in $ip ..etc.... sed -i will do in place editing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I have used is Vi.

(sudo) vi /home/mydoc.txt   will open and allow you to do any editing you need done.  If you have never used Vi before, there are some great HOW-TO's and tutorials online.  Here is one:

http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/

But I'd encourage you to really read and experiment on test files before you change the file you are referencing, AND, PLEASE, make a backup up the file ( cp /home/mydoc.txt mydoc.txt-orig ) before you do.  You can always remove the edited file that does not work, but restoring the original after extensive exiting can be a hair-pulling experience.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed to do this for example some thing like this 
Note:every space is escaped by \ [sed Intro](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html)

```
   cat server.conf | sed 's/server-bridge\ 192.168.50.225\ 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.50\ 192.168.10.90/server-bridge\ 192.168.10.100 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.60\ 192.168.10.80/' > server.conf
```

or you can use two files for safety like this

```
cat server.conf | sed 's/server-bridge\ 192.168.50.225\ 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.50\ 192.168.10.90/server-bridge\ 192.168.10.100 255.255.0.0\ \ 192.168.10.60\ 192.168.10.80/' > server.conf.bak
cat server.conf.bak > server.conf
```

Comment: You should not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `sed` and `awk`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v ip='192.168.10.100' -v mask='255.255.0.0' -v bip='192.168.10.60' \
 -v eip='192.168.10.80' '/server-bridge/{$2=ip "(ip)"; $3=mask "(mask)"; $4=bip "(begin";
 $6=eip "(end"} 1' server.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed to change all lines containing `server-bridge`:

```
sed -i -e '/^server-bridge/!b' \
    -e 'c server-bridge 192.168.10.100 255.255.0.0  192.168.10.60 192.168.10.80' input
```

to change th 115th line only:

```
sed -i -e '115!b' \
    -e 'c server-bridge 192.168.10.100 255.255.0.0  192.168.10.60 192.168.10.80' input
```